# No Items in Array Message in HTML table row

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a table that receives data from my dataService.js file and then loops through each employee in the array and creates a new row to display the employee. Right now I have it set up to display a message if no employees are hired yet however it shows it above the table and I would like to do it still as a row in the table if none are found.

What do I need to do to correct a mistake I'm making?

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Street</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Zip Code</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="employeeList.length === 0">No employees hired.</tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="employee in employeesList track by $index">
        <td>{{employee.employeeName}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.employeeStreet}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.employeeCity}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.employeeState}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.employeeZipCode}}</td>
        <td><span ng-click="deleteEmployee(employee)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**

Anyone else know why its showing up above my table?

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Street</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Zip Code</th>
        <th class="actions">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="employeeList.length === 0">
        <td colspan="6">No employees hired.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="employee in employeesList track by $index">
        <td>{{employee.employeeName}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.employeeStreet}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.employeeCity}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.employeeState}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.employeeZipCode}}</td>
        <td><span ng-click="deleteEmployee(employee)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ng-if="employeeList.length" have you tried this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work fine if you use valid html. Browsers will kick out invalid html and display it outside of where it was found

Text can't be inserted directly in a `<tr>`. Use a `<td>`

```
<tr ng-if="employeeList.length === 0"><td colspan="6">No employees hired.</td></tr>
```

Comment: Only issue is after I upload my page file and refresh my browser I don't get anything inside of my HTML table, but yes I do agree I should have noticed that to begin with.

Comment: The refresh issue doesn't sound related to this

Comment: All I did was update the line of code you suggested.

Comment: adding one properly formatted cell shouldn't make data not appear

Comment: That's strange because everything else in the script still works. I'll repost what I have now.

Comment: double check open/close tags is all i can suggest

Comment: I just did. The only warning/errors I get are warning me about the angular specific issues in the elements.